# How do I switch between sounds seamlessly in c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application that will need to move between sound files, playing them seamlessly, one after the other. From what I have read, the best way to do this is to play the files synchronously in a thread.

I have written a class that properly plays the files in the correct order, but there is a definite noticeable gap between tracks.  The tracks themselves are working fine; if i play them in any order in windows media player, they lead into one another without problem.

Thank you very much for any help!

```
    public static class AudioPlayer
    {
        //make the thread that contains the loop to play music
        private static Thread musicLoopThread = new(PlayLoop);

        private static bool outrocalled = false;
        private static int snippetIndex = 0;
     
        //make my media player
        private static System.Media.SoundPlayer musicPlayer = new();

        private static byte[]? introSnippet;
        private static byte[]? outroSnippet;
        static List<byte[]> snippetList= new();

        static MemoryStream? introStream;
        static MemoryStream? outroStream;
        static List<MemoryStream>? streamList = new();

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //get byte arrays from files
            introSnippet = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\snippets\intro.wav");
            outroSnippet = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\snippets\outro.wav");

            snippetList.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\snippets\0.wav"));
            snippetList.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\snippets\1.wav"));
            snippetList.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\..\snippets\2.wav"));

            //turn byte arrays into memorystreams
            introStream = new MemoryStream(introSnippet);
            outroStream = new MemoryStream(outroSnippet);

            for (int i = 0; i < snippetList.Count; i++)
            {
                streamList.Add(new MemoryStream(snippetList[i]));
            }

        }

        public static void Play() //called from a form button to start playing
        {
            //start the thread that will loop the audio
            musicLoopThread.Start();
        }

        public static void Stop() //called from a form button to set the loop to end soon
        {
            outrocalled = true;
        }

        private static void PlayLoop()
        {
            //Play the intro
            musicPlayer.Stream = introStream;
            musicPlayer.PlaySync();


            while (!outrocalled)
            {
                //set up the next snippet
                musicPlayer.Stream = streamList[snippetIndex];
                streamList[snippetIndex].Position = 0;

                //play the next snippet
                musicPlayer.PlaySync();

                //increment and loop back to 0 if necessary
                snippetIndex++;
                snippetIndex %= streamList.Count;
            }

            //play the outro
            musicPlayer.Stream = outroStream;
            musicPlayer.PlaySync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doubtful you'll be able to appropriately achieve this with the fugly SoundPlayer class on every system this code will run on, unless it has built-in functionality for this. The tiny amount of time passing between waiting for one stream to end and queueing the next one most likely causes the crackling pause. You probably want to invest into a more sophisticated solution like NAudio.

Comment: Why are you using `MemoryStream` instead of file paths and `SoundLocation`?

Comment: I tried your code with some sounds I had from Cisco Jabber and I didn't hear any issues?

Comment: @NetMage I originally used SoundLocation and switched to MemoryStream hoping that the gap between files would be smaller  accessing a byte[] rather loading a file between synchonous plays.  I'm not sure if it made a difference, just because the gap is so small anyway, but definitely enough that it is audible in code that is meant to loop seamlessly